# Pinout for movesense Sensor

Tags: movesense

I have encountered a problem with the DFU mode of my senor. Probably caused by my own application.

I compiled and uploaded a sample application with the newest firmware (1.4.1 ) and bootloader and it worked like a charm. Then I uploaded my own firmware without the bootloader, this resulted in a semi responsive device, where i can see the device but not connect to it long enough to set it in DFU mode. I tried to manually set it in DFU mode by removing the battery, shorting the terminals, waiting and removing the short as described in the FAQ but the device still refuses to enter DFU mode.

As I have a j-link and pogopins I would like to flash the sensor myself, but can't find a pinout for the sensor (I have seen that movesense (Suunto) has a programming jig but would like not to buy more equipment due to limited storage space). Does anybody have a pinout for the sensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer when version 1.5.0 of the firmware was released. They added a pdf with the pinout to the movesense-device-lib. 
The pdf with the pinout can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/Mechanics/Sensor/)!